# Get a custom bean on an abstract class

Tags: java, spring

I have this class that gets the configurations from the application.properties to create the driverto connect to the database (im using jdbc to connect to my database):

```
@Component
public class JdbcConfiguration {

@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String url;
@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String user;
@Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
private String driver;
@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String password;

@Bean
public void setUpDriver() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(url);
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(user);
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(password);
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
  }
}
```

I have also an abstract class called JdbcDao to create all tools necessary to connect to the database:

```
@Component
public abstract class JdbcDao {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
private JdbcConfiguration jdbcConfiguration;

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

public JdbcDao() {
    JdbcConfiguration a = context.getBean(JdbcConfiguration.class);
    DriverManagerDataSource driver = context.getBean(DriverManagerDataSource.class);

    this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(driver);
}

public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplateObject() {
    return jdbcTemplateObject;
 }
}
```

Then, I have the concrete representation of that jdbc abstract class:

```
public class JdbcUserDao extends JdbcDao implements UserDao {

public JdbcUserDao() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void save(User entity) {
    System.out.println("save");
}

@Override
public void delete(User entity) {
    System.out.println("delete");
}

@Override
public User findById(Long id) {
    return getJdbcTemplateObject().queryForObject(QueryConstants.User.GET_USER_BY_ID, new Object[] { id },
            new UserMapper());
}
}
```

But when I do new JdbcUserDao() I have a NPE because the application context is not being injected, which causes a null pointer when trying to get my custom bean.

Why is the applicationContext not being injected? How can I solve this?

Edit:

- StackTrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at com.arqsoft.gorgeousSandwich.data.jdbc.JdbcDao.(JdbcDao.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.arqsoft.gorgeousSandwich.data.jdbc.JdbcUserDao.(JdbcUserDao.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.arqsoft.gorgeousSandwich.data.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionType(DatabaseFactory.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.arqsoft.gorgeousSandwich.services.user.impl.UserService.getUser(UserService.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.arqsoft.gorgeousSandwich.controllers.UserController.index(UserController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_231]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_231]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]

- Class that instantiate JdbcUserDao:

DatabaseFactory:

@Component
public class DatabaseFactory {

```
@Value("${connection.type}")
private String connectionType;

public UserDao getConnectionType() {
    DatabaseConnectionType type = DatabaseConnectionType.getDatabaseConnectionType(connectionType);
    switch(type) {
        case JDBC_CONNECTION:
           return new JdbcUserDao();
        case JPA_CONNECTION:
           return new JpaUserDao();
        default:
            throw new NoDatabaseConfigExceotion(); //EXAMPLE EXCEPTION
    }
}
```

}

Component that calls the factory:

- UserService:

  ```
  @Service
   public class UserService implements IUserService {

  @Autowired
  DatabaseFactory userDatabaseConnection;

  @Override
  public User getUser(Long id) {
      return userDatabaseConnection.getConnectionType().findById(id);
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If you are literally doing what you say you are, doing `new JdbcUserDao()`, then that's why `ApplicationContext context` is not getting populated in that object.  You can't instantiate a Spring Bean (that is, a Spring managed/injected instance) via `new`.  If you do, Spring won't know anything about it, and so won't scan it, and so none of the annotations on that class or its subclases will have any effect on that instance of the class.  You need to get your app's BeanFactory, and then instantiate the class by asking the BeanFactory for a copy of the Bean that is an instance of that class.  That class has to have been registered with Spring so that it knows about it and can instantiate it.

Unless you're doing so in XML somewhere, I don't see that `JdbcUserDao` has been registered with Spring as a Spring Bean.  You need to annotate it so that it is a Spring Bean, and then get an instance of it via a call to a `BeanFactory`.  Only then will the annotations in that class take effect and will that instance be wired up by Spring.